# How to push source code from isolated git via master to jenkins slave

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

We've got the following issue:

We have an internal git and jenkins master protected by a firewall and want to deploy source code from the git to jenkins slaves which are located outside the firewall e.g. at AWS/Azure/GCP etc. There is no way that the slaves will get a VPN or similar to the internal network.

I've found the "copy-to-slave" plugin for jenkins which isn't what we're looking for but a good start. We think it should be a feature of the jenkins git-plugin to use the master as a proxy and push the source code from there into the workspace on the slave. It would be possible with a second job run on the master cloning the repository and rsyncing it to a slave but this would double the amount of configured jobs on the master.

Is there a possibility to achieve this with existing tools/plugins and without a second job?

Comment: Did you take a look at https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over

Comment: That would be a way, but this wouldn't be usable with dynamically spawned slaves. We would also need to run bash commands on the master/slave machine, which we would like to avoid at all costs.